# Are temp table indexes unique across sessions or are they shared?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a large query (Web Dashboard Query) with many temporary tables.i have created indexes on the temp table.the application that is using the query has a user management module with different levels of permissions.My question is are indexes created per session like the temp db ?
i don't want the indexes to be shared across sessions.

i have been doing something like

```
EXEC('CREATE INDEX idx_test'+ @sessionId + 'ON #TempTable (id1,id2)');
```

is this necessary. i have seen it done by some developers.

Comment: Yes for temp table, it is applicable to the session only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes on temporary tables (#t, not ##t) are not shared across the sessions, and there is no need to invent a unique index name to an index on a temporary table.

What is different (and may be you have seen in the code from other developers) is `CONSTRAINT` NAME. Index name can be repeated many times for different tables, but a constraint name must be unique within the database.

So maybe you see the code for stored procedures that create a constraint name with reference to a session, this is an attempt to give a unique name to a constraint. Because if you launch a stored procedure that creates a temp table #t in two sessions, every session create it's own table with it's own name(not just #t, the system is adding additional symbols to a table name that makes it unique)

But if the same proc tries to create a CONSTRAINT PK_t, the first session will succeeded but the second will get an error that the constraint PK_t already exists in the database(tempdb)